# Issue with a do while loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, methods

The program below takes the customer age and verify if the customer is eligible to see a certain movie. I am having an issue with CustomerAgeCheck() method. Every time I enter age above 100 or below 0, the loop continues to run infinitely and no result is shown on the label.

```
protected void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AgeVerification();
        CostOfTickets();
    }
    protected int CustomerAgeCheck()
    {
        int age = int.Parse(Cust1AgeTextBox.Text);

        do
        {
            ageVerificationLabel.Text = String.Format("Please enter the correct age");

        } while (age < 0 || age > 100);

        return age;
    }
    protected void AgeVerification()
    {
        int age = CustomerAgeCheck();

        if (Movie3RadioButton.Checked && age < 17)
        {
            ageVerificationLabel.Text = String.Format("Access denied - you are too young");
        }
        else if (Movie4RadioButton.Checked || Movie5RadioButton.Checked || Movies6RadioButton.Checked && age < 13)
        {
            ageVerificationLabel.Text = String.Format("Access deniad - you are too young");
        }
        else
        {
            ageVerificationLabel.Text = String.Format("Enjoy your Movie");
        }
    }
    protected void CostOfTickets()
    {
        int cost;
        int totalTickets = int.Parse(CustomerDropDownList.SelectedValue);
        cost = totalTickets * 10;
        resultLabel.Text = String.Format("Your Total is {0:C}", cost);
    }
```

Comment: n Why would you use a loop, at all? In `AgeVerification` you have similar logic to do input validation. Why did you switch to something else in `CustomerAgeCheck`? Keep in mind that if this is asp.net (based on how you tagged this) the value in `Cust1AgeTextBox.Text` will only change after the user post the form again. You can't *wait* in a loop for a new value to come in. That is not how the web works.

Comment: You never change the value of `age`, so the condition is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very bad logic, especially since you're working with a GUI and you have events to help you.

All you have to do is to add a **NumericUpDown** control, set the min to 0 and max to 100 and then listen to the **ValueChanged** event.

In this event, you can simply use your above code:

```
    age = (int)NumericUpDownAge.Value;
    if (Movie3RadioButton.Checked && age < 17)
    {
        ageVerificationLabel.Text = String.Format("Access denied - you are too young");
    }
    else if (Movie4RadioButton.Checked || Movie5RadioButton.Checked || Movies6RadioButton.Checked && age < 13)
    {
        ageVerificationLabel.Text = String.Format("Access deniad - you are too young");
    }
    else
    {
        ageVerificationLabel.Text = String.Format("Enjoy your Movie");
    }
```

You can also disable/enable controls based on the age entered in the NumericUpDown and make your GUI much more interactive and/or self-explanatory.

Comment: This is what I did in the HTML/Asp.Net. Enter Age: <asp:TextBox ID="Cust1AgeTextBox" runat="server" Width="41px" TextMode="Number" min="1" max="100" step="1"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 0):

```
do
        {
            ageVerificationLabel.Text = String.Format("Please enter the correct age");

        } while (age < 0 || age > 100);
```

The problem is very simple. It is with the above block of code. you don't have a break condition. When you enter a value above 100 or below 0 into age, its value doesn't changes in the execution of loop. Hence the while loop returns true always (Because the condition is whenever age > 100 and age < 0, repeat the loop) and continues to execute. You should edit it to meet the termination condition according to your need.

When you enter some other value after executing once, as the while loop condition fails it will terminate.

Comment: The OP tagged their question as asp.net. *Update the age to a value in between 0 and 100* will not happen in the loop if they are running this as code behind in some webpage.